# Send broadcast from one Android app to another

Tags: android

I currently have 2 apps in the market, let's call them app A and app B.

When a certain function is executed in app, I need something to trigger an event in app a, even if app a isn't currently running. I assume app B would send a broadcast message to app a and app a would need a broadcast receiver but I am not sure how this can be done, if it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two ways afaik:

- [Broadcast Receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and using the [sendBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) method on the sender side

or by using Intents:

- you can use startActivity(Intent) even with another app, but this will bring the app to foreground rather than doing a job in background.

Use intents if the calling app should dissappear and the called app should be in foreground and use broadcasts if you just want a background task performed by another app

Answer (score 2):

Can be done, even if the app isn't running, with BroadcastReceiver, just like you said.