# Launch single BroadcastReceiver form another application

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I created an Application that shares a BroadcastReceiver that launches a Service.

The app that holds the receiver doesn't have activities, there are the receiver class and the services.

Here are the manifest declaration:

```
        <service
            android:name=".services.PrintService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="art.bridge.PRINT_MESSAGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Receiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(ArtAppl.name , "Receiver reached");
        Intent print = new Intent(context, PrintService.class);
        if(intent.getStringExtra("message") != null)
            print.putExtra("message",intent.getStringExtra("message"));
        else
            print.putExtra("message","Message not found");

        context.startService(print);
    }
}
```

Form an another app, i try to launch the receiver like following:

```
        Intent bReceiver = new Intent("art.bridge.PRINT_MESSAGE");
        sendBroadcast(bReceiver);
```

But the receiver doesn't run.

Am I missing something? Do I have to set another action in the manifest?

Comment: Can you post the source of `.MyReceiver`? Are you seeing anything in LogCat if you put a `Log` statement in `onReceive()`?

Comment: @MichaelDodd nothing is printed if i try to log it. Now i post the code of the receiver

Comment: Another question, what version of Android are you testing against? Are you seeing any warnings/errors regarding unprotected broadcasts in Logcat?

Comment: I'm testing on 6.0.1, no warnings

Comment: Give this a go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492790/how-to-send-broadcast-from-one-app-to-another-app

Specifically, `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you need to include `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` as a flag?

See: [How to Send BroadCast from one app to another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492790/how-to-send-broadcast-from-one-app-to-another-app)