# Broadcast Receiver not showing result when broadcasting from another app Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to make `broadcast receiver` which will show a `toast` message when user click on `button` from **my another app activity**.

But `receiver` not showing result.

My code is below

**My Receiver App**

**MyReceiver**:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast has been received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Manifest**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.xyz.broadcasts"></action>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>
```

**My sender app**

My `MainActivity` which sends the broadcasts is here.

**MainActivity**:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void SendOutBroadcast(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.example.xyz.broadcasts");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xyz.broadcasts.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="SendOutBroadcast"
        android:text="Send Broadcast"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try to log some text ..have you debug that the broadCast onreceive method is working.?

Comment: no i did not debug. ok let e add log.

Comment: yes logs must work if broad cast is receiving message.

Comment: Couldn't load memtrack module, this error is shown in stacktrace. is it the problem ???

Comment: You can check this post for error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629568/couldnt-load-memtrack-module-logcat-error

Comment: Debug window shows this:
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast | com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast | com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast | com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast | com.example.xyz.receivebroadcast.test
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.

Comment: this is because you have not define your activity in Manifest file

Comment: i think you are in debug mode.go to file-> invalidate cache and restart the android studio . This will help to get out of debig mode or you can simply attach debugger to it.

Comment: can you post you xml code where you have SendOutBroadcast event

Comment: @MuhammadArslanMaqsood is this your complete Manifest file

Comment: post edited, please check

Comment: Yes you haven't declare your activity in manifest @UltimateDevil answers is correct.

Comment: @Muhammad Arslan Maqsood, I am able to run your code and it's working perfectly fine. I just added one activity in Receiver app to run it.

Comment: @MdSufiKhan do you Edit configuration for MyReceiver from Run menu ? I have changed launched activity to nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case your `activity` **`Intent`** should be like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.xyz.broadcasts");
intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setComponent(  
        new ComponentName("com.pkg.AppB","com.pkg.AppB.MainActivity"));  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Try this may help you or [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492790/how-to-send-broadcast-from-one-app-to-another-app) for more information.

**NOTE** - This may be not going to work in **Android O** because in Android O **`implicit broadcast`** are ban as mentioned **[Here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html)**. (Also credits to you @Muhammad Arslan Maqsood)

Comment: @MuhammadArslanMaqsood have you test this.? i think this might be the right answer.

Comment: i am checking. please wait

Comment: still not woking. name field(".MainActivity") in activity tag is getting red.

Comment: yeah i must mention here is . i have edited configuration launcher setting to No launch activity. is that a problem ?

Comment: add package name before your activity name as mentioned in updated answer get a look like - com.example.xyz.MainActivity

Comment: aahh, still not working ... ".MainActivity" is still red

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: @Muhammad Arslan Maqsood it shows red in `.MainActivity` as your receiver app doesn't have `MainActivity` class.

Comment: have you checked that MainActivity and Receiver both are in same package .?

Comment: i have two apps, one is sender app and other is receiver app.

Comment: I think in his receiver app there is no `MainActivity`. There is only one `MyReceiver` class.
And in his sender app there is a `MainActivity`.
Am I right?

Comment: Actually i am not getting your concept of sender app and receiver app why you want to do this you can call broadcast in single app

Comment: yes but what i am trying to learn is, how to receive broadcast from any other app. which is built by any other developer.

Comment: Have you try to log some values or text in you receiver App ..?? put some sample text and log that value on onReceive method of receiver App.Check its working or not.?

Comment: @MuhammadArslanMaqsood i have add a edited my answer try may this help you

Comment: i found the issue: issue is not with code, actually Android O disabled the feature "Implicit broasdcast". see this https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html

Comment: last code which @UltimateDevil edited (ComponentName) is working fine.

Comment: Glad this works for you. I need to update or edit my answer and your question too. Because you did not mention that you are receiving broadcast fromnother app. May this help anyone else

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue: issue is not with code, actually Android O disabled the feature "Implicit broasdcast". see [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html)