# Android - How to send data to another app without bringing it to the foreground?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

We are planning to link our app with another person's app, and we would like to know, how would we be able to in Android for our app to send data to that other person's app without bringing the other app to the foreground?

Would this solution work?:
[How to Send BroadCast from one app to another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492790/how-to-send-broadcast-from-one-app-to-another-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I would like to know for sure before I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Send your data using a broadcast `Intent` and implement a `BroadcastReceiver` on the receiving app. This will not automatically bring the receiving app to the foreground.