# How pass data from manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver to activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have been looking for solutions for this, but there doesn't seem to be any.  I have a fairly unique use case that I need to be able to pass data between two different apps even when one app isn't active, therefore my BroadcastReceivers need to be registered in the manifest.  However, what I can't seem to figure out is how I pass the received data from my manifest-registered BroadcastReceivers to my activities.  Most of the examples are using dynamically registered BroadcastReceivers, which will not work in my use case.

Comment: You can use a `Service` and inside that you can register yours BroadcastReceivers.

Comment: "how I pass the received data from my manifest-registered BroadcastReceivers to my activities" -- there may not be any activities. If the receiving app did not have a process running, Android will fork a process to respond to the broadcast, but there will be no running activities in that process. " I have a fairly unique use case that I need to be able to pass data between two different apps even when one app isn't active" -- perhaps you should ask a separate Stack Overflow question, explaining the nature of this flow, and asking for advice on how best to implement it.

Comment: You seem to be basing your assumptions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56118445/115145), and while Dave's answer is correct, a broadcast is not the only option. It may not be the best option. However, without **details of what you are trying to accomplish**, we cannot give you much assistance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383756/android-best-approach-for-inter-app-communcation-without-foregrounding-them

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is hard to say without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, two solutions come into mind; one being [receiving with permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) and the other is WorkManager to schedule work regardless of your user is using your app or exited your app.